# How can I avoid getting useless warnings while building my package using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

It seems that setuptools triggers various warnings that are really of zero value and I want to get rid of them as they are spamming the continuous integration progress, making just harder to spot real warnings.

Here are those that I do want to get rid of:

```
python setup.py -q bdist_wheel
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.md' under directory 'releases'
warning: no files found matching '*.rst' under directory 'releases'
warning: no files found matching '*.json' under directory 'releases'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'examples/node_modules'
no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/node_modules'
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
```

It seems that all these are caused by the [`MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest-template) file but the conditions there do have a reason for being there, and that's clearly not the one of generating warnings when exclude patters do find no files to match?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment I found only one workaround for this issue:

`export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=`

This will avoid getting these annoying warnings during the build.

Answer (score 1):

I use a makefile to build my project and I had to add the following line to the top:

`unexport PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`

In shell, you must `unset PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`, too. Setting it from `1` to `0` won't work. I am using `zsh` though, so maybe the answer above will work elsewhere.

Also, you can pass `-B` to `python` directly to disable byte-compiling, but the environment variable takes precedence over it (at least in the Python 3 version I am using - `3.6.8`). I do not see an option to force turning on byte-compiling, though.

Lastly, you can pass `--help` to most `setup.py` commands to get info on flags they support. For example, `build_py` and `install_lib` support `--compile/-c`, `--no-compile` flags which should help you with fine-grain control, although the environment variable again takes precedence from my experience.